# How can I enable fetchmail on OS X Mountain Lion?

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, fetchmail

Snow Leopard came with fetchmail, but in Mountain Lion seems to be missing. Homebrew doesn't have a formula for it either.

What's the best way to get back fetchmail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Homebrew does have it, but it's in the separate [homebrew-dupes](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes) repository. So to install:

```
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew install fetchmail
```

Comment: Thanks, but there seem to be some issues with this recipe. It tries to download http://prdownload.berlios.de/fetchmail/fetchmail-6.3.21.tar.bz2, which really is a stupid JavaScript redirect.

Comment: Looks like the receipe in dupes was finally fixed. Thanks for the hint! I had to patch it with "--with-ssl", so this and the answer by @steve-ulrich are both kind of correct.

Answer (score 0):

the following gist is a formula which will address this issue.  if you go to the aforementioned link (to download the fetchmail source code) and place it into /Library/Caches/Homebrew and then run the gist. you'll get the homebrew version of fetchmail.

https://gist.github.com/3261452